# subspace of the global sections of $\mathcal O$$(D)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $D$ an effective divisor whose complete linear system $|D$ is base point free and $D^2=1$. Suppose the dimension of $|D|$ is greater than or equal to 3. Is there a subspace of the global sections of $\mathcal O$$(D)$ which is also base point free?

Comment: In the first sentence I guess "base point" should be "base point free".

Comment: @Pop Yes, you're right, I mean $|D|$ is base point free

Comment: The answer is yes. Take a general pencil in $|D|$; we can choose divisors $D_1$ and $D_2$ spanning the pencil which are smooth and irreducible and meet transversely in a single point $p$ (using the fact that $D^2=1$). Now choose any divisor $D_3 \in |D|$ not passing through $p$. Then $D_1, D_2, D_3$ span a proper subspace of $|D|$ which is basepoint-free.

Comment: Welcome to MO. Your question is quite reasonable, but note that it is not considered proper etiquette on MathOverflow to revise or generalize your question in the comments. You may edit your question, but if you do that, don't remove the first part, just add a second paragraph: "More generally, is something similar true for smooth varieties, or even for non-regular varieties and schemes?" Your second option is to ask a new question with the more general situation, in which case it should include a link back to this question as having answered the dimension 2 case.

Comment: Is there an example other than $X = {\bf P}^2$ and $D = O(1)$?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: that's not an example satisfying all of OP's conditions, since in that case $|D|$ has dimension 2. Indeed now that you ask, I see there are no such examples. But if one drops the OP's condition that $D^2=1$ the answer is still yes (replace the single point $p$ in my comment above by $D^2$ points).

Comment: Ah, I can never remember whether "$|D|$" means the vector-space dimension
or the projective dimension . . .

Comment: @Pop Please forgive my stupidity. Can you expalin more in detail why $D_1$ and $D_2$ meet transversely in a single point provided $D^2=1$?

Comment: I do not really like talk of "stupidity". I am happy to explain. Since $|D|$ is basepoint-free, Bertini's theorem guarantees that the general divisors $D \in |D|$ is smooth and irreducible. Choosing $D_1$ and $D_2$ to be two such general divisors, they are then distinct irreducible curves in $X$, so meet in a finite number of points. The intersection number $D^2$ can be computed as the number of intersection points of $D_1$ and $D_2$ counted with multiplicity. Since $D^2=1$, there is only 1 such point $p$, and the intersection multiplicity is 1, so the two curves meet transversely at $p$.